# Iterate over specifified sheets in a workbook with python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I would like to iterate over sheets 3 to 9. So a total of 7 sheets will be looped over. How to I specify they sheets to loop over?

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('DemoFile.xlsx')

for sheets 3 to 9 in wb.worksheets:
    print(Sheets)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `range` to specify which sheets to iterate based on the index of the sheet. `openpyxl` uses 0-based indexes, so sheet 3 has an index of 2.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('DemoFile.xlsx')

for n in range(2,9):
    print(wb.worksheets[n])
```

Output:

```
<Worksheet "Sheet3">
<Worksheet "Sheet4">
<Worksheet "Sheet5">
<Worksheet "Sheet6">
<Worksheet "Sheet7">
<Worksheet "Sheet8">
<Worksheet "Sheet9">
```